# Dynamic editable form with UITableView and storyboard

Tags: ios, uitableview, dynamic

I'm trying to create a edit user information page for the user that is using my app, which their editable info would include something like: name, surname, phone numbers, emails, etc.

So I want to create a form using a UITableView with prototype cell in storyboard for each type of data, but here's the catch: There can be a variable amount of each type e.g. user can add or delete emails. Each cell might have a text field for the user to modify their data.

My question is, **how do I retrieve the information entered into each cell**? Because their can be a variable amount of each cell, I cannot statically tie each field to a property in my class.

Comment: You want like edit contacts in iPhone where just add cells according to their suitability.

Comment: @KrishnaKumar exactly

Answer (score 0):

You can make custom cells according to the type of cell. So whenever user want to add any field then they can select from your predefined type of cells. It will be easy for you to retrieve data according to their type and they also can multiple field of same category or other category..

You can give option to add a custom cell in which label and textfield will be.. then label text can be retrieved as category and textfield can be retrieved as value for that category. To recognize the type of category you can mention the category in a picker. And write the code for the validation of that type of cell. And if their id other category jus put its type as string. Likewise you can retrieve both value and type.

Comment: Yeah, but how do you retrieve data from those cell, since each field in the cell is not tied to any variable, if you scroll up or down, it might be lost.

Comment: then don't use dequeuereusable method in tableView just make your custom cell. And store all your cell object in an array..

Comment: So can I still use storyboard for this? Or do I have to create a custom cell with xib instead. Don't know how to retrieve the prototype cell from the storyboard without using dequeuereusable.

Comment: You can use storyboard and then subclass the UITableviewcell. And change the custom class field in identity inspector of your custom cell in storyboard with your subclass.

Comment: Then how do you use that subclassed UITableViewCell? Don't you still have to init it from the storyboard? How do I do that?